# Why chmod folder in php not working?

Tags: php

I create folder and chmod:

```
 $mypath = "CSV/" . $dateTimeNow;
 mkdir($mypath, 0777, TRUE);
 chmod($mypath, 0777);
 $tmp='abc.csv'
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $mypath . '/' . $tmp);
```

file abc.csv has icon lock.
I can't read data from file abc.csv .Why? Can you help me? thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with `has icon lock`? What icon lock? And where?

Comment: He has a "lock icon" in some filesystem explorer, indicating that he have no rights to access file.

Answer (score 3):

Many default server config do not accept `777` permissions, Try `0757`. Check server error log for more info...

```
if ( ! file_exists($mypath))
{
    mkdir($mypath, 0757, TRUE);
}
```

**EDIT:**

If folder/file is already created try `chmod` over the file:

```
chmod($mypath . '/' . $tmp, 0644);
```

Comment: folder $mypath is still lock

Comment: Is apache not permision chmod folder?

Comment: if i call chmod ($mypath, 0757). folder not lock, but file in folder is lock.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning access rights with `chmod` for a **directory**, while your file has **other** access rules. Try applying `chmod` to a file after you move.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure csv folder is created inside the directory where php file where this code is written